# VSCode: What is the command to open the selection in a new windows (vertical split?)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I am in QuickOpen:

[image]

I would like to use "ctrl-v" to open this file in a split window.

[image]

Currently, I can do so with by "cmd+enter" in this QuickOpen dialog.

I can't seem to find the keybinding for this in the default keybinding json.

Can someone help me out?

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+v"
    "command": <--
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be in v1.44:

> **New command to open editor to the side**
>
> A new command `workbench.action.alternativeAcceptSelectedQuickOpenItem`
>   allows to bind a key to open files or symbols from quick open to the
>   side.

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#quick-open-rewrite

So I presume this will work:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+v",
  "command": "workbench.action.alternativeAcceptSelectedQuickOpenItem",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
```

---

Tested in standard version of vscode v1.44: this does work.  It will open a file in a split editor from the QuickOpen panel.

---

I assume you already have the setting

> Editor: Open Side by Side Direction

set to `down`.  Only other option is `right`.

Comment: It is in the Insiders' Build now - will be in v1.44 later this week.

Comment: Works! Thank you. Is there a way to control whether the window opens up on left or right?

Comment: I don't believe so - there is a setting for opening to the side with options `right` and `down` - so I think you are limited to that.  Nor is there any specific `open to the left` sort of command.

Comment: @Mark - awesome answer - any guesses why I can't map this to `Ctrl + Enter`?  It's the common key command  for `explorer.openToSide` and `openReferenceToSide`.  Even if I remove the conflicting key commands, and set the scope to `inQuickOpen` the keybinding doesn't work with `Ctrl+Enter`.