# How do you open file in split editor in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this:

[image]

And I want to add a keyboard short cut such that it will open the file in a new split window like this:

[image]

In my keybinding.json, what is the name of this action?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767160/vscode-what-is-the-command-to-open-the-selection-in-a-new-windows-vertical-spl/61094934#61094934 The new command is `workbench.action.alternativeAcceptSelectedQuickOpenItem`

Answer (score 18):

There is a keyboard shortcut for this, `breadcrumbs.revealFocusedFromTreeAside`

`Ctrl+Enter` (macOS: `Cmd+Enter`) in the **Quick Open** `Ctrl+P` (macOS: `⌘P`) file list.

see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_side-by-side-editing

Likewise you can do this from the Explorer with `explorer.openToSide`

Comment: Unfortunately, explorer.openToSide is only referring to the explorer panel. I am specifically looking for something that will open the file under the cursor in Quick Open.

Comment: @Sparrowcide see my full answer above the explorer.openToSide line, that was just a way to do it from Explorer in addition to Quick Open.

Comment: cmd alt click opens in side.

Answer (score 2):

Just press `Ctrl + \` when you search for the file